# Unable to use property binding

Tags: angular

I tried property binding in angular2 as follows and it shows error as

**Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'tile'.**

Binding of tile

```
  <tile [data]=value></tile>
```

Definition of component

```
@Component({
    selector:'tile',
    template:`{{data.newvalue}}<br>`,
    Inputs: ['data']
})
export class tile {
   public data:String;
}
```

I am using angular RC5

Comment: Are you sure the `tile` component gets instantiated? Can you also please try a different name (like `datax`)?

Comment: I tried changing to other names and I even tried @Input() instead but it throws the same error

Comment: Then it looks like the component is not instantiated at all. You can check by adding an constructor with `console.log('hello world')` and check if it gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the component to `declarations: []` of your `NgModule` and to `exports: [...]` if you want to use it from another module (where you need to import the module).

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Answer (score 0):

Give it like this :

```
@Component({
    selector:'tile',
    template:`{{data.newvalue}}<br>`,

})
export class tile {
   @Input() data:string;

}
```

and it will work.